# IIS 8.5 Default Document Not Working

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an issue with IIS when I browse my asp .net application . I get 404 error. 
and it seems to be navigating to localhost:59/ while I want it to go to localhost:59/login_page.aspx

I added the page to list of Default Documents ..but still I get the same error.

I have followed several instructions on the internet but nothing seems to solve this problem.

please help

Comment: set your login page as the default page in VS?  (right click - set as default)

Comment: i have done that already. still same result.